# Spring partial bean validation in PATCH request

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm making a Spring Boot application. I have an entity there:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @NotNull
    private Category category;

    // Education related fields
    @NotNull
    private Education education;
    @NotBlank
    private String eduName;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate eduGraduationDate;

    // other fields, getters, setters ...
}
```

As you can see, I have validation annotations there. But in my application I need to update the fields partially, e.g. client wants to update `Education` fields separately from `Category` field.

And the problem is that I cannot use PUT request to do that, because it will update whole object. If the `Category` field is actually `null`, and I want to update just the `Education` fields, I will get `ConstraintViolationException`, because the `Category` field is `null`. But it was `null` and I want it to be `null` further.

I can use PATCH request to do this:

```
@PatchMapping(path = "/{id}", consumes = "application/merge-patch+json")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> patchEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody JsonMergePatch jsonMergePatch) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException {
    Employee employee = employeeDataService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not exist: id = " + id));
        
    Employee employeePatched = applyPatchToEmployee(jsonMergePatch, employee);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeDataService.save(employeePatched));
}
    
private Employee applyPatchToEmployee(JsonMergePatch jsonMergePatch, Employee targetEmployee) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode patched = jsonMergePatch.apply(objectMapper.convertValue(targetEmployee, JsonNode.class));
    return objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, Employee.class);
}
```

**But the question is: How can I validate my fields partially?**

For example, if I send a PATCH request with body:

```
{
    "education":"HIGHER",
    "eduName":"MIT",
    "eduGraduationDate":"2020-05-05"
}
```

How can I validate only this 3 fields? Not the whole `Employee` object? In this example, as I mentioned above, I want the `Category` field to be `null` and I don't want to validate it, if it is not included in the patch.

Maybe there are some better approaches to partially update entities, if so - which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new DTO object with only fields you want to include for your PATCH call like,

**EmployeePatchDto**

```
public class EmployeePatchDto {

    // Education related fields
    @NotNull
    private Education education;
    @NotBlank
    private String eduName;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate eduGraduationDate;

    // other fields, getters, setters ...
}
```

but now you'll still have to be sure that these validations are considered when you call the API.
Also, you can opt to validate your DTO class at controller method level by using `@Valid` like this,

```
public ResponseEntity<Employee> patchEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody EmployeePatchDto employeeDto) throws JsonPatchException, JsonProcessingException {
```

I'l leave this resource for you. [Read this.](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/)

Comment: I was thinking about this approach. Is it a common pattern to do that?

Comment: @MaxBobr Yes, it is. But there are other ways too. The doc I mentioned contains other methods as well, validating entity at Service level, creating your own custom validation annotations and then finally to have your own Validator. Having a `Validator` gives you the freedom to trigger validations anywhere you want to. I had a POJO with about 200 fields once to validate. I finally settled with a Validator after months in production. Please use whatever way suits you.